# Why does removing a reference to resource in java does not lead to garbage collection

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
fis.readAllBytes();
```

why does fis = null does not make this stream object ready for garbage collection
why does it lead to memory leak
why do we have to close the stream object

Comment: Garbage collection is not immediate.

Comment: `fis = null` is a variable assignment. It’s not the purpose of variable assignments to close files. If you want to close the file, use the statement dedicated to close a file. Or better, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).